# local Ajax call success but no data returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've created two projects in Visual Studio 2010 one is a Web Service and the other is a web application, I have a method on the web service as follows:

```
`[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/getData")]
    List<Objects> TestCall();`
```

Once I run the service I can happily type in the URL to get the JSON response:

`http://localhost:17258/RestService.svc/json/getData`

results in

`{"TestCallResult":[{"id":1,"name":"Title"},
{"id":2,"name":"Title"},{"id":3,"name":"Title"},{"id":4,"name":"Title"}]}`

However in my web application when I try and make this Ajax call to get this response I get a success from the call but the JSON is null, here is my ajax call:

```
`$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:17258/RestService.svc/json/getData",
                type: "GET",
                mimeType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (json, status) {
                    alert("Success JSON=" + json + ", status=" + status);
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                    for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
                        alert(obj[i].id);
                    }
                }
            });`
```

I'm trying in FireFox and the json variable comes back as null, when debugging in IE debugger I can add a watch to the object and can see the object has the array underneath it, do I need to use json.TestCallResult instead or has anyone else seen this difference between IE and FireFox OR can someone say stop being a noob and do this...

Thanks

Comment: Is your website (the one from which you are calling the webservice) also located on localhost:17258 or does the server responding on port 17258 send a header containing an Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting?

Comment: When you debug in IE which value has the json var?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax url should have the same host:port as your html's url.

Answer (score 0):

In your success callback u already get an json object. If u try to parse this with $.parseJSON again, the result is null. http://jsfiddle.net/H4v8G/

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `json.d` instead of `json`.

The response data is included in the `.d` property, and not directly in the returned object.

This happens with ASP.NET 3.5 and later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:17258/RestService.svc/json/getData",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (obj) {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length; i++) {
                        alert(obj[i].id);
        }
     }
});
```

Try this